# Javascript switch not working with <option> tag values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<select id="rankBox">
    <option value="0">100</option>
    <option value="1">150</option>
    <option value="2">200</option>
    <option value="3">250</option>
    <option value="4">300</option>
    <option value="5">350</option>
    <option value="6">400</option>
</select>

<input type="Submit" id="button1" value="Generate" onclick="doStuff()">
```

and the following **Javascript**:

```
function doStuff() {
    var choice = $("#rankBox option:selected").val();
    console.log(choice);
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            colorQ = "^7";
            break;
        case 2:
            colorQ = "^L";
            break;
        case 3:
            colorQ = "^A";
            break;
        case 4:
            colorQ = "^8";
            break;
        case 5:
            colorQ = "^+";
            break;
        case 6:
            colorQ = "^<";
            break;
        default:
            alert("Something went wrong");
            break;
    }
    alert(colorQ);
}
```

In short, I have a switch statement which is supposed to check the value of the option the user has selected. As you may see, I have added `console.log` to see if the problem is with acquiring the user's input, but that is not the issue. The issue is the switch statement, which just does not work.
Am I using wrong syntax or something?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qTHW/2/ (jsFiddle doesn't work in my browser at all, says doStuff() is not defined)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jsFiddle says doStuff() is not defined as you've set the JavaScript in your jsFiddle as "onLoad" instead of "No wrap- in <head>", so the JavaScript `doStuff` function is wrapped in a `function(){...}();` block and not accessible.

Comment: Actually you're misusing `switch` here, the [job could be done](http://jsfiddle.net/95HB8/) with an array and one `if...else`.

Comment: Cheers, I've never even heard of using arrays with if statements but I'll try it out!

Comment: @Teemu Since values 0 and 1 should both give the same color, how would I do this? Just add the color twice in the array?

Comment: @jCuber Yep, exactly that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not** an integer, it's a string, as all values from an element are strings.

You'll have to either parse it as an integer :

```
function doStuff() {
    var choice = parseInt( $("#rankBox option:selected").val(), 10);

      ....etc
```

or change the switch to work with strings (you should be trimming)

```
switch ( $.trim(choice) ) {
    case '0':
    case '1':

     ....etc
```

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't even realize Javascript had integers and strings. How silly of me. Thank you, it works now. (I can accept the answer in 9 mins)

Comment: By the way, what's the reason for the `, 10` after the `.val()` ?

Comment: It's the radix, specifying the decimal system (10), without it you could have issues with some numbers being parsed as octal (8) etc.

Answer (score 1):

This was an easy problem, by looking at the code one could see that the line var `choice = $("#rankBox option:selected").val();` is adding string to variable choice. And that is the reason none of the case statements worked and the default code executed.

The best way not to run into such problems is to "Debug" your JavaScript code properly. This will save you a lot of precious time and you will find the root cause to each problem yourself.

To debug your code, you can use Firebug extension in Firefox. This will actually stop the code execution for you and guide you line by line telling you the state of each variable at every line of code. So in case of your problem, all I did was add your code in .html file and ran it in Firefox with "Debugger" points specified. The JS code looked like this.

```
function doStuff() {
    var choice = $("#rankBox option:selected").val();
    debugger; // This is the point where the debugging starts

       console.log(choice); // console.log wont help as it did not tell me the type
    switch (choice) { // Here Firebug tells me that choice is actually a string
        case 0:
        case 1:
            colorQ = "^7";
            break;
        case 2:
            colorQ = "^L";
            break;
        case 3:
            colorQ = "^A";
            break;
        case 4:
            colorQ = "^8";
            break;
        case 5:
            colorQ = "^+";
            break;
        case 6:
            colorQ = "^<";
            break;
        default:
            alert("Something went wrong");
            break;
    }
    alert(colorQ);
}
```

Note I put a "debugger" above console.log(). From this point onward, the code stopped at each line and I could see the value in each variable. This helped me notice string value in choice.

Happy Debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript parseInt() method like this :

var choice = parseInt($("#rankBox option:selected").val());